# Program to take a set of n numbers and display them after removing the smallest number (without using arrays)?

Tags: c

I have written code to find the smallest number from the set:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    int i,n,sm,N;
    printf("How many numbers? \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Enter the first number:\n");
    scan("%d", &n);
    sm=n;
    for (i=i;i<=(N-1);i++) {
        printf("\nEnter another number:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n<sm) {
         sm=n;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe smallest number is %d", sm);
}
```

I am unable to think of a way to modify the code so that I can remove the smallest number AND display the remaining numbers in a single line.

Comment: Use linked list instead of array. or recursive call (The display will be in reverse order.)

Comment: Do not post images of code.

Comment: investigate the use of a stack

Comment: This seems like a highly contrived problem. Why can't you use arrays?